# childprocess.stdout.on('data', callback) not firing

Tags: node.js, stdio, spawn

I'm trying to capture the output from a child process and send that through a websocket but I'm having problems capturing the `on.(data, callback)` event.

```
var subscriberProc = spawn('./stdoutsub', 
                      ['mytopic', '--clientid', 'node-dispatcher'], 
                      {cwd: '/Users/oskar/projects/others/rsmb_1/mac/'});

subscriberProc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('-> "' + data + '"');
  wsServer.send(data);
});
```

If I change to the following, the stdoutsub process prints to the node process stdout with the expected data.

```
var subscriberProc = spawn('./stdoutsub', 
                      ['mytopic', '--clientid', 'node-dispatcher'], 
                      {cwd: '/Users/oskar/projects/others/rsmb_1/mac/', 
                       stdio: 'inherit'});
```

I'm running node version 0.8.1 on OSX.

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue (where I was missing the output in certain cases) and concluded that the spawned process is spewing output before I get a chance to start listening for it.

I solved it by using code similar to below from Node.js documentation :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
    err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

var child = spawn('prg', [], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
});
```

And then I read out.log and so far things have worked out fine for me.